# Setting application config *not* user config

Tags: android

I have developed a main app, now I need to develop a second app which is identical to the first but only perform 70% of the functionality. I have modularized the main app's functionality but now I want to be able to turn them on/off base on a configuration file. The values in this configuration file need to be accessible within the context of Activities and Services. A lot of people suggested using SharedPrefences, but I don't need end user to modify this. It's only meant for developer to configure these settings. What's the best approach for this?

Comment: If this is for a free version vs. paid version, you could instead put the 70% in the free app and the remaining 30% in an add-on paid "upgrade key" app, and use [signature-level permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) and a [shared UID](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) to link them together.  Many apps use this approach, such as [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher).

Answer (score 0):

Now in android data can be stored in [these ways](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Now you don’t want to store configuration in shared preference, So i would suggest you to go in 2 ways
Create a SQLite database that is accessible by both apps OR 
Create a file that stores the configuration data and is accessible by both apps

Whatever the method that you choose to store the data encrypt it using some encryption algorithm like this

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
  }
```

And invoke them like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); // bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  

byte[] keyStart = "this is a key".getBytes();
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
sr.setSeed(keyStart);
kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();    

// encrypt
byte[] encryptedData = encrypt(key,b);
// decrypt
byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(key,encryptedData);
```

Now you can use the key to access these values and user would not be able to understand you configuration information

or you can use a web service to save data onto the server and your both apps can use that web service to get the configuration, It wont work offline though :(